# PHP array_push incorrectly pushing data

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to push an altered array to a class member, but for some reason it's just replacing the first element with the second.

```
class Registration {
  var $formID;
  var $formKeys;
  var $registrations = array();

  function __construct($a) {
    $this->formID = $a;

    global $wpdb;
    $keys = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_nf3_fields WHERE parent_id = '.$a);

    $labels = array();

    foreach($keys as $key) {
      $labels['_field_'.$key->id] = $key->label;
    }

    $this->formKeys = $labels;

  }

  function get_registrations() {
    global $wpdb;

    // Get IDs of fields
    $IDs = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID WHERE wp_posts.post_type = "nf_sub" AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = "_form_id" AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = "'.$this->formID.'"');

    foreach ($IDs as $id) {
      $id = $id->ID;

      $regs = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = '.$id);

      $events = unserialize($regs[8]->meta_value);

      $numberOfEvents = count($events);

      $tempEvent = "";

      foreach($events as $key => $value) {
        array_push($this->registrations, $regs);

        $this->registrations[count($this->registrations)-1][8]->meta_value = $events[$key];     

      }

    }

    $registrations = $this->clean_up_data($this->registrations);

    return $registrations;
  }
}
```

You can see what it returns at this URL. https://www.ulmaonline.com/tournament/tournament-information/

I know I have to be missing something very simple. But I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: After your constructor runs, `registrations` is an associative array (ie, key / value pairs, hashmap, etc). `array_push()` only adds values at numeric indices

Comment: If you take out the second last line, or rather do a var_dump before the second last line, is the problem still there? i.e. could the problem be in     $registrations = $this->clean_up_data($this->registrations);

Comment: @Phil $registrations is just a regular ol' array. I don't reference key/value pairs within the code for it.

Comment: Ah sorry, I got it mixed up with `formKeys`

Comment: @GavinSimpson if I print_r($this->registrations[count($this->registrations)-1]) inside the foreach($events) it displays data at [8]->meta_value correctly. If I do print outside of the foreach it is incorrect. The [8]->meta_value is repeated twice of whatever the last data saved to it was.

Comment: @Phil, no worries! The issue almost looks like a scoping problem, but that's not the case.

Comment: If you look at the source on the link above you will see how it spits out the results. I put a print statement inside foreach($events as $key => $value) that prints this print_r($this->registrations[count($this->registrations)-1]); and then one after that foreach. You can see that inside the foreach the results are correct, but the one outside of the foreach the data is incorrect.

Comment: Are you displaying all php errors and warning? That might help if you are not.

Comment: And as a crazy idea, try using     $this->registrations[]=$regs; instead of array_push. Should be the same thing though. I'd also add $this->registrations=array(); just before the loop. U never know :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an answer to this bug, but I did find a work around for getting done what needed done. If someone figures this out that would be awesome.